# php making images clickable

Tags: php, image, click

Need a little help making my images clickable. I've tried everything and whenever i do the images break and won't show. The code was provided on the site and i was trying to add pagination to my page and now another error occurs with click the images and seing the images

```
while( $file = readdir( $open ) ){

  $ext = strtoupper( pathinfo( $file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );

  if( in_array( $ext, $allow ) ){

    $modifyTime = filemtime( $dir . $file );
    $list[ $modifyTime ] = $file;

  }
}

# reverse sort on key
krsort( $list );

$perPage  = 20;
$total    = count($list);
$pages    = ceil($total/$perPage);
$thisPage = isset($_GET['pg'])?$_GET['pg']-1:0;
$start    = $thisPage*$perPage;

echo "Page "; 

// show pages
for ($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++):

  if ($i==$thisPage) :
    print "&nbsp;".($i+1); 
  else :
    print "&nbsp;<a href='?pg=".($i+1)."'>".($i+1)."</a>"; 
  endif;

endfor;

// show images
$items = array_slice( $list, $start, $perPage );
foreach( $items as $image ){
  echo "<a href='$dir/$file'<br/> " . $image . "<br/><img width='200' height='200' src='" . $urlPath . $image . "'/><br/></";
}

closedir($open);  
?>
```

Comment: There's some sloppiness in that last `echo` statement that could be the culprit. Missing at least one `>` and one `a>`

Comment: mopo922 thats my fault //its me trying to make the images clickable

Comment: @Eddie_ what happens if you clean it up? Looks like both the opening & closing `<a>` tags are incomplete.

Comment: @mopo922 same thing happens no images are shown

Comment: What does the generated source code look like and is that what it is supposed to be (paths correct, etc.)?

Comment: In your foreach, you have a <br /> tag within an anchor that should be removed.  I would also add some alt text to your image tag (alt="Something") to see if the problem is that the code isn't being rendered properly or if the problem is that the images aren't being found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not escaping your variables properly within the quotes:

```
echo '<a href="' . $urlPath . '/' . $image . '"><img src="' . $urlPath . '/' . $image . '" width="200" height="200" /></a>';
```

Comment: it sends it to the directory folder "uploaded" and not the image that was clicked

Comment: I've edited my answer. If you want them to go to the image when they click it, you need the anchor's href to be the same path as the image.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
echo( "<a href='$dir/$file'><img width='200' height='200' src='$urlPath/$image'/></a>") ;
```

-your "<a href..." has no ">", then it needs a closing tag "</a>"
-there's no "/" between $urlPath and $image (or is the "/" in the $urlPath string?)